# Can a page be half responsive and half not?

Tags: html, responsive-design, web

We are creating a site which is responsive. However, due to time constraint, we need to make a few pages only work for the desktop viewport. The pages have a top navigation which is responsive. Is it possible that when accessing that page from a mobile, the navigation is responsive, but the rest of the page just loads completely adaptive (like a non-responsive site would load on the phone)?

Please advise.

Comment: Sounds like you need to research how media queries work. It's definitely possible.

Comment: Sounds that they dont have the time to make media querys for all pages.

Comment: What about building the site with a custom version of bootstrap? Bootstap provides an easy tool for creating custom version, in which you could include the navbar(It'll make the navigation responsive). Later, If you want any additions, simple add the new custom bootstap version.

Comment: anything you don't specifically make responsive won't be responsive. in this case, your media query should only include styles for the nav element(s). pay attention to any percentage widths/heights on the rest of the page - they *may* cause you problems

Comment: This just calls for an opinion about play with words.

Comment: So this is what I am asking if it's possible: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s269/sh/4e6ec3a7-26b5-4982-a9b4-1a54215d3474/26e94fc58dfd605b456f0adf57ba1e7d

Can this be achieved with ease? and how? If not, can we have all elements on this page as non-responsive... even the nav doesn't change when a user reaches this page from a mobile? Can that be plan-B?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think, that this would work very well.

How would you put two 1000px and a 300px width element on one page so that they both use 100% of the screen?

Maybe you can make a responsive page with navigation an all and load the pages you dont get responsive in an full size iframe below the navigation. But dont know if this would work very well. Also iframe handling, like scrolling etc is a bit picky on mobile devies.

Comment: Will it work like this: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s269/sh/4e6ec3a7-26b5-4982-a9b4-1a54215d3474/26e94fc58dfd605b456f0adf57ba1e7d???